# Defining an array type with matching pairs (like domino bricks) in typscript

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to create a type alias in typescript to which all values are assignable that are arrays of Pairs and where each pair matches the succeeding pair like domino bricks do: Pair<A,B> matches Pair<C,D> if and only if B = C.

Example values:

```
const chain1: DominoChain = [ ["A","B"], ["B","C"], ["C","D"], ["D","E"] ] // OK
const chain2: DominoChain = [ [3, 4], [4, 2], [2, 1] ] // OK
const chain3: DominoChain = [ [3, null], [null, {}], [{}, undefined] ] // OK
const chain1: DominoChain = [ [1, 2] ] // OK
const chain1: DominoChain = [ ] // OK
const chain1: DominoChain = [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ] // Not OK because 2 !== 3. The compiler should raise an error
```

Here is what I have so far, but it is not working:

```
type Domino<A,B> = [A, B]

type DominoChain<A = any, B = any> = [Domino<A, B>] | [Domino<A, B>, ...DominoChain<B, any>]
```

I don't known how to properly define the matching constraint between two Domino pairs and I'm doing something wrong with the recursion part.

Comment: Just curious, what is the use case?

Comment: The last time I tried to implement this, I want to store functions with a single input and a single output in a array and each function should be callable with the result of the previous one. You could think of it as a array version of the chain of responsibility.

But it is not limited to this use case.

Comment: It is very similar to compose function. You can take a look on my article https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to express in typescript type system such restriction without validating generic argument.

However, it is possible to create a type utility which will validate your input.

Consider this example:

```js
type Last<T> = T extends [...infer _, infer LastElem] ? LastElem : never

type Head<T> = T extends [infer First, ...infer _] ? First : never

type IsChainable<Current, Next> =
  (Last<Current> extends Head<Next>
    ? (Head<Next> extends Last<Current>
      ? true
      : false)
    : false)

type DominoChain<List extends any[], Result extends any[] = []> =
  (List extends []
    ? Result
    : (List extends [infer First]
      ? (IsChainable<Last<Result>, First> extends true
        ? [...Result, First]
        : never)
      : (List extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
        ? (Result extends []
          ? DominoChain<Rest, [...Result, First]>
          : (IsChainable<First, Head<Rest>> extends true
            ? DominoChain<Rest, [...Result, First]>
            : never))
        : never
      )
    )
  )

type Test1 = DominoChain<[["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "E"]]>
type Test2 = DominoChain<[[3, 4], [4, 2], [2, 1]]>
type Test3 = DominoChain<[[3, null], [null, {}], [{}, undefined]]>
type Test4 = DominoChain<[[1, 2]]> // ok 
type Test5 = DominoChain<[]> // ok

type Test6 = DominoChain<[[1, 2], [3, 4],]> // never

const domino = <
  Elem extends string,
  Tuple extends Elem[],
  List extends [...Tuple][]
>(list: [...List] & DominoChain<[...List]>) => list

domino([["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "E"]]) // ok
domino([[1, 2], [3, 4],]) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AHgCoD4oF4qqhAD2AgDsATBKAbQDo6BLEgMwgCcoB9AGikZffhIAogBsIAWwC6UAPyxEwURKgAuKCQgA3NgCgdoSFAASEOGTSYceQsXKUqfNlABi9Vkh50aj9h2lzXd2BVdS1dfXBoAEkEAGEACzhGOAAjMWRYgFdWVlJgHgA5G0sdKCgACkEULJy8zBtSCmNTcyKidFKy2QqTM2Q24HqiRsoqjOzckkHOru7gVkyIGa61JjgRBAgASmXV9c2diMMAEQB7cUZThKSSZBh6JHxhuyg4EhAqSR4AJQgETJEwQaLzeH2kOE%20JTKlQeQOeTU%20yzkv3%20gN2FXuj2BCJ8LjcSEkyzKcnKMWuyTSEDuCmQKIBgx4gSQQ1sTXmiyJXTktDodMBjPxwEJs1mag02lYOxFIRhWPh9lxTPyUC8uJRQs5xIqfLhrPswulXKgZwuJCuiUYtL%20yp5NB1AqCkg6hpWFTJFpIqXSSp4vXM6vQLJGUHZSxdszkJsu5Nu6p4tvteMdzvDZTFYUlUsN6YlnKzZSzhwM0FQ1oAjNhjedox7kFQqAAiACCDZ4DYAQg2vtQO62oA3Yl34wO%20w3jkOe%20O20Iu06jiXrQAmStRs0xutUADMPAALN2qDueIv94ueGXJHPi7hrZuV9W17X69v1ACRPuSK%20eABvAC%20%209-PCZOQEBMIwEBkBeHRXqWSA7neprmjcG5lkekFQAA9OhUCnAA1lA87XkgACs8E1khkIYVhuF6NB1oAGykQ%205FUChUDHvGz57lwTqUaEuY6AAxqcJCPGQ96nJWyCdEo4hPHqUBIKwjAAOZcJ0qCZGAYhycGMmfGpZSYrqwa2hpWkQJIiLoOUIiwmotpGdIABkVYIeuDmwk6WzYJgtlIHoYkIeU9bNqOnb7r2baDhFg5tuOEVTv2M4Xt5mHYThOiBZcwUsahHG7l8kipVhbCsKcrBAA)

`Last` - obtains last element in the tuple
`Head` - obtains first element in the tuple

`IsChainable` - checks whether last element in current tuple extends  first element from the next tuple and vice versa. Pretty straightforward.

`DominoChain` - iterates through list of tuples and calls `IsChainable` on each tuple.

It is a lot of code but it is really not so complicated once you get it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the huge example! Your example looks close to what I already tried, but I stopped proceeding at the point, where I had to define an extra function or constant for type checking reasons only. It is all about checking an inferred type against an existing type definition, which is currently not possible without workarounds such as your domino-function, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, in order to do such things you always need to use extra utilities. From the other hand, if you know upfront all elements in the mail list it is possible to create a permutation of all allowed states, but such approach might hit recursion limit

Answer (score 0):

With the hint from @captain-yossarian that you need to add an additional function or constant for this type checking to work, I created this solution:

```js
// Definition of the domino brick
type Domino<A = any, B = any> = readonly [A,B]

// The definition of the array wiht matchin domino bricks
type DominoChain<T extends readonly Domino[], FIRST = any> =
    T extends readonly [Domino<any, infer A>, ... infer REST]
        ? (REST extends Domino[] ? readonly [Domino<FIRST, A>, ...DominoChain<REST, A>] : never)
        : readonly []

// This avoids type inference at an undesired place
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];

// This function must be used to compare a inferred type against 
// the definition of DominoChain
function dominoTest<T extends readonly Domino[]>(domino: T & DominoChain<T>): NoInfer<T> {
    return domino
}
```

```js
dominoTest(<const>[ ["A","B"], ["B","C"], ["C","D"], ["D","E"] ]) // OK
dominoTest(<const>[ [3, 4], [4, 2], [2, 1] ]) // OK
dominoTest(<const>[ [3, null], [null, {}], [{}, undefined] ]) // OK
dominoTest(<const>[ [1, 2] ]) // OK
dominoTest(<const>[ ]) // OK
dominoTest(<const>[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]) // error
// TS2345: Argument of type 
// 'readonly [readonly [1, 2], readonly [3, 4]]' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type 
// 'readonly [Domino<any, 2>, Domino<2, 4>]'.   
// Type at position 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.     
// Type '3' is not assignable to type '2'.
```

Update: Improved the original code example